# Content of div partially hidden behind header when the link to the div on same page is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the contents of `<div a id="contentAbout">`to fully appear when I click on the btnAbout link after scrolling down to the bottom of the page it is on, but when the link is clicked, and page jumps back to the top, the top part of the content is hidden (by a few lines) behind the `<header>` element, which is and needs to always remain in position at the top of the page (as per `position: sticky;` in the css).  I need the top part of the `contentAbout` div to show under the header.  I use plain javascript to display each div block as and when the links or buttons are clicked.  This problem occurs regardless if it a link with an anchor to the div on the same page or a button with no anchor link that just executes the javascript to display the block.  I believe the issue lies in the css, but not sure where or what to research to resolve this issue.  Using Chrome.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav class="nav">
                <h1><a href="index.html">website name</a> | <span id="contentHeading"></span></h1>

                <a href="index.html#contentAbout" id="btnAbout" name="btnNav" value="about"
                    onclick="contentAbout();">about</a>

                <input type="button" id="btnPortfolio" name="btnNav" value="portfolio" onclick="contentPortfolio();" />

                <input type="button" id="btnResume" name="btnNav" value="resume" onclick="contentResume();" />

                <input type="button" id="btnContact" name="btnNav" value="contact" onclick="contentContact();" />

                <input type="button" id="btnBlog" name="btnNav" value="blog" onclick="contentBlog();" />
            </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div id="hidden"></div>

            <div a id="contentAbout">
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et pariatur doloribus nemo temporibus dolor
                earum iure. Consequuntur consectetur inventore aperiam quae sed, quis doloremque fugit iste placeat
                dignissimos fuga, saepe nemo, maiores ipsum aliquid voluptas? Ut ea ex iusto. Asperiores eligendi
                assumenda corporis aspernatur laborum animi quas impedit. Molestias quos fugit, exercitationem sequi
                blanditiis, dolores maxime numquam illo nesciunt delectus nihil quis est quia sit facilis quod. Officia
                ipsam minima voluptatibus distinctio esse cum repellendus obcaecati? Tempore consectetur blanditiis
                alias sequi aspernatur sunt architecto recusandae ratione, numquam aperiam quasi sit asperiores delectus
                praesentium minima quo voluptates nihil reprehenderit. Fugiat nulla assumenda laudantium reiciendis
                enim? Ut iste, magni voluptates, aut quo earum obcaecati nemo voluptas enim nam voluptatem impedit vero
                debitis quasi similique. Nam eveniet est aperiam magni odit necessitatibus architecto a nobis deleniti
                saepe quas fugit numquam sed cumque, culpa molestias ratione temporibus exercitationem, ex sapiente!
                Optio iste laboriosam dolores repellat eveniet, id enim rem provident porro est corporis minima nulla
                mollitia ex cum quidem neque? Omnis quas tempora vel odio. Commodi, reiciendis iure! Voluptatibus,
                sequi. Impedit ad sed est aperiam laboriosam eligendi veniam nobis perspiciatis optio labore sapiente
                cum quos tenetur minus, ipsam ducimus quod eius eum qui. Aut tempora, excepturi dignissimos delectus
                voluptate consequatur qui! Consequatur, saepe modi quo, ipsam sunt eum tempora aperiam, nemo tenetur
                totam possimus repellendus ex minus laudantium! Accusamus fugiat id aliquam, quos eos exercitationem
                dolor, officia ea officiis enim libero ab dolores adipisci eligendi iure labore nam. Nobis, totam
                voluptatem! Itaque adipisci, explicabo corporis perspiciatis provident at doloremque nesciunt odio
                facilis error maiores culpa nemo vitae, exercitationem dolorum facere officia sequi optio enim et alias!
                Nihil suscipit delectus libero, repellendus rem quas eius neque cum vel esse tempora incidunt sed earum,
                veritatis voluptate fugiat praesentium rerum perspiciatis alias voluptatibus dicta. Id debitis eos,
                excepturi delectus deleniti ad omnis consequuntur reiciendis reprehenderit molestiae eligendi ratione et
                ipsa, cumque similique incidunt voluptas magnam, iure quas dolorum aliquid? Quia culpa doloremque
                nostrum eligendi consequatur iste similique hic qui eos illum non commodi numquam beatae deserunt, odio
                facere deleniti consectetur? Enim dignissimos at dolore eum, velit, nesciunt culpa ad fugit sunt
                corrupti asperiores obcaecati! Ex in molestias itaque! Autem necessitatibus modi debitis, deserunt
                quisquam quasi sapiente molestiae eaque et dolores sint voluptas, amet quod sed. Eaque numquam porro
                molestiae quae consequuntur commodi harum, non impedit veniam beatae vitae reiciendis, nulla aut libero!
                Mollitia cupiditate, minus corporis temporibus neque quisquam itaque unde consequuntur maiores eum
                pariatur esse culpa odit nobis voluptates architecto harum impedit ducimus iste earum tenetur nesciunt
                veritatis! Modi officiis voluptas eaque repudiandae suscipit aut ipsa itaque. Facilis perspiciatis
                eligendi a blanditiis rem earum omnis suscipit voluptate nisi minima laudantium perferendis est aperiam,
                hic similique doloribus. Necessitatibus blanditiis magnam nostrum ipsa aliquid voluptates molestiae
                aperiam. Ullam, consectetur, minus atque deserunt consequatur libero possimus quaerat repellat veniam
                officia magni quos, est perferendis sunt cupiditate dolores nulla aspernatur iste? Quas cum, magnam
                possimus eveniet quisquam sapiente vel hic sit cupiditate, recusandae iste atque quam aperiam veniam
                temporibus voluptatum assumenda ut eius est odio, perspiciatis nisi commodi. Eos mollitia rem dolores
                voluptatum optio nihil corrupti doloremque numquam. Iure ratione inventore eaque? Numquam ducimus id
                porro tempora sapiente laborum voluptate recusandae soluta. Iste placeat ipsa officia autem sequi
                consequuntur commodi, quibusdam maxime debitis facere animi temporibus pariatur veritatis molestiae enim
                reiciendis tempora omnis aspernatur ea ullam atque error vel vero? Cum quibusdam, illum, quam
                perspiciatis sunt earum maiores itaque est, repellendus minima et. Laboriosam, nulla facere esse nihil
                ut dolore rerum odit asperiores? Quam quo amet alias sit fugiat repellendus sed, iusto voluptatibus,
                assumenda nihil eaque aperiam laudantium quasi expedita error autem ullam, impedit quidem odit quas
                delectus quos provident. Provident, ea iusto alias, libero qui iste voluptatum laborum saepe rerum
                veniam sit dolorum, quam nemo minus ratione nesciunt eaque eius. Dolores iusto suscipit eius fuga ut
                nemo libero quam, aperiam alias facere magnam, necessitatibus iure cupiditate voluptas? Ducimus nihil
                assumenda quam fugit ea pariatur sint, fuga reprehenderit incidunt neque, qui animi alias iure? Harum
                fuga aperiam, voluptatibus est adipisci reprehenderit quos assumenda ipsam, saepe ad nisi ut alias
                molestias voluptas at facilis quod maiores ratione dolorum eos aliquid iure! Ut itaque repellat,
                doloribus deleniti quaerat voluptas, cupiditate aperiam eum error sunt vel quis iusto inventore iste
                sint esse. Deleniti natus impedit sunt, assumenda et atque earum minus fugiat excepturi consectetur
                harum tenetur eos eum labore eaque dolorum quaerat omnis sequi maxime! Incidunt, dignissimos expedita?
                Eum, non ducimus deserunt quod veritatis minus sunt animi ab nostrum dolorem impedit sint officia
                tempora alias obcaecati perspiciatis hic quisquam molestias! Expedita itaque praesentium cupiditate
                possimus rem earum optio natus ut. Nobis voluptatum inventore ex, laborum a voluptates dolorum ullam
                corrupti, voluptatem nostrum voluptate. A error eveniet, natus veritatis illo eos accusantium labore
                repudiandae exercitationem ex modi omnis eligendi mollitia dignissimos ipsam deserunt obcaecati soluta
                molestias dolores rerum velit porro. Aperiam totam inventore, accusantium molestiae ex assumenda dolore
                ratione molestias vel. Modi molestias harum, id distinctio labore eius deserunt rerum illo, magni esse
                quis quibusdam sit sed. Nisi facilis quibusdam ullam veniam aliquam quae labore unde a, dignissimos
                rerum magnam esse. Ipsam temporibus dolorum error adipisci suscipit iusto? Nemo illo velit molestias et
                at esse nisi. Dolore explicabo, ut nemo earum repellendus, pariatur, inventore eligendi nobis provident
                corrupti delectus! Veniam voluptate ratione deserunt modi blanditiis corporis aliquid, nisi facilis ex
                similique dolorum magnam! Explicabo provident voluptatum, enim ipsam ullam adipisci amet suscipit veniam
                in consectetur voluptates dolorum repellendus deleniti facilis. Debitis molestiae rem, facere eaque
                doloremque perferendis voluptas sed molestias sint ipsam odit eius placeat, libero, tempora numquam
                illum iure? A debitis sint in veritatis, atque adipisci distinctio quaerat eligendi cupiditate
                recusandae labore quod minima tempora, voluptates fugiat! Nostrum est consequatur ullam corporis,
                recusandae atque, obcaecati quibusdam totam quae similique in minus error. Voluptate unde adipisci neque
                molestias illum debitis. Aliquam, assumenda? Quisquam commodi consequuntur pariatur reprehenderit minus
                harum sunt labore accusantium quibusdam! Aliquid iusto quaerat architecto culpa aliquam mollitia
                pariatur, assumenda nostrum suscipit fugit modi perspiciatis beatae accusantium quis voluptatum, alias
                explicabo unde.
            </div>

            <div id="contentPortfolio">
                Here are my projects.
            </div>

            <div id="contentResume">
                My work experience.
            </div>

            <div a id="contentContact">
                My email.
            </div>

            <div a id="contentBlog">
                Here are blog post listings
            </div>
        </main>



        <footer>
            &copy; all rights reserved
            <div id="nav2" class="nav">
                <a href="index.html#terms">[terms]</a>
                <a href="index.html#privacy">[privacy]</a>
                <a href="index.html#disclaimer">[disclaimer]</a>
                <a href="index.html#webmaster">[webmaster]</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#content-wrapper {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: justify;
  align-content: center;
}

  header {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: sticky;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    display: block;
  }

  main {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }

  #contentAbout, #contentPortfolio, #contentResume, #contentContact, #contentBlog {
    display: none;

  }

  footer {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    display: block;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
function contentAbout() {
        if (document.getElementById("btnAbout").click) {

            document.getElementById('contentHeading').innerHTML = "About";
            document.getElementById('contentAbout').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contentPortfolio').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentResume').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentContact').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentBlog').style.display = "none";

        }
    }

    function contentPortfolio() {
        if (document.getElementById("btnPortfolio").click) {

            document.getElementById('contentHeading').innerHTML = "Portfolio";
            document.getElementById('contentPortfolio').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contentAbout').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentResume').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentContact').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentBlog').style.display = "none";
            

        }
    }

    function contentResume() {
        if (document.getElementById("btnResume").click) {

            document.getElementById('contentHeading').innerHTML = "Resume";
            document.getElementById('contentResume').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contentAbout').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentPortfolio').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentContact').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentBlog').style.display = "none";
            
        }
    }

    function contentContact() {
        if (document.getElementById("btnContact").click) {

            document.getElementById('contentHeading').innerHTML = "Contact";
            document.getElementById('contentContact').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contentAbout').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentPortfolio').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentResume').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentBlog').style.display = "none";
            
        }
    }

    
    function contentBlog() {
        if (document.getElementById("btnBlog").click) {

            document.getElementById('contentHeading').innerHTML = "Blog";
            document.getElementById('contentBlog').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contentAbout').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentPortfolio').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentResume').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('contentContact').style.display = "none";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is there a reason for introducing the anchor element (which also 'has an onclick event listener) and also is there a reason for using input elements rather than ordinary button elements? Incidentally, reverting to just the input rather than an anchor element for the About seems to do the right thing in terms of positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that when I scroll the content of a div  & then change the tabs the content of a div is hidden because window was scrolled to a position & the scroll position of window remained same even when I changed the tabs so the content appeared to be partially hidden.
to fix that you can add this in all the functions you call on clicking the buttons :

```
window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
```

for example :

```
function contentAbout() {
  if (document.getElementById("btnAbout").click) {
    document.getElementById("contentHeading").innerHTML = "About";
    document.getElementById("contentAbout").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("contentPortfolio").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("contentResume").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("contentContact").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("contentBlog").style.display = "none";
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
}
```

**Just a opinion** :
Instead of calling different functions when you click those buttons , you can make 1 function like this :

```
function tabChange(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case "about":
      document.getElementById("contentHeading").innerHTML = "About";
      document.getElementById("contentAbout").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("contentPortfolio").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentResume").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentContact").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentBlog").style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "portfolio":
      document.getElementById("contentHeading").innerHTML = "Portfolio";
      document.getElementById("contentPortfolio").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("contentAbout").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentResume").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentContact").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentBlog").style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "contact":
      document.getElementById("contentHeading").innerHTML = "Contact";
      document.getElementById("contentContact").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("contentAbout").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentPortfolio").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentResume").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentBlog").style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "resume":
      document.getElementById("contentHeading").innerHTML = "Resume";
      document.getElementById("contentResume").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("contentAbout").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentPortfolio").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentContact").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentBlog").style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "blog":
      document.getElementById("contentHeading").innerHTML = "Blog";
      document.getElementById("contentBlog").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("contentAbout").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentPortfolio").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentResume").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("contentContact").style.display = "none";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

& then on the html do like this :

```
<input type="button" id="btnAbout" name="btnNav" value="about" onclick="tabChange('about')" />

     <input type="button" id="btnPortfolio" name="btnNav" value="portfolio" onclick="tabChange('portfolio')" />

     <input type="button" id="btnResume" name="btnNav" value="resume" onclick="tabChange('resume');" />

     <input type="button" id="btnContact" name="btnNav" value="contact" onclick="tabChange('contact');" />

     <input type="button" id="btnBlog" name="btnNav" value="blog" onclick="tabChange('blog');" />
```

Hope this helps  [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/abhikb/pen/wveyYZV?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you @abhikb..this is exactly what I needed!  You have taught me something new and I appreciate your contribution.  I tried upvoting your answer but SO says I need 15 rep points to do so.  But, thank you all the same - - really helpful.

Comment: I am glad to know my answer was helpful to you : )